# Calculate probability based on multiple tries, multiple outcomes and one more variable.

Tags: probability

I need a way of calculating probability based on multiple tries, multiple outcomes and one more variable. I will give you an example. Imagine, that you have an orange juice store. For example, there are 100 people going in the store daily looking for orange juice and 50 different brands with different prices. What is the probability, that one of those brands is going to be bought by at least one of the customers, having in mind, that the lower the price is, the higher the chance. I was thinking of multinomial distribution, but I have no data based on previous events.

Comment: This is far too vague.  If you have a store, you can look at actual sales and work up the distribution that way.  If you have a model in mind (something that you think predicts when people will or won't buy) you could implement that.  But, surely, you don't imagine that there is a simple calculation that covers all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but as said by @lulu in the comments, it's far too vague. There is no one calculation, not even for set variables. For example, how higher will the chance exactly be? We need at least some definition. How much is the cost of each brand? There are too many factors to generalize.

Hope that helped,

-FruDe